# Python sqlite query with bindings splits it by characters

Tags: python, sqlite, binding

```
some_list = ['11', '22', '33']
for i in some_list:
    c.execute("INSERT INTO dbtable (dbcolumn) VALUES (?)", (i))
```

Returns error:

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 2 supplied.
```

It explode `'11'` into characters.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that the parameters need to be a sequence:

```
    c.execute("INSERT INTO dbtable (dbcolumn) VALUES (?)", (i,))
```

The **comma** makes it a tuple, NOT the parens/brackets.

---

Alternatively if you can make each list element a tuple you could make use of the `.executemany()` method:

```
sequence_of_sequences = [('11',), ('22',), ('33',)]
c.executemany("INSERT INTO dbtable (dbcolumn) VALUES (?)", sequence_of_sequences)
```